# Forcing Fullscreen at a custom resolution

Tags: windows-7, fortnite-battle-royale

Ok, so my laptop is garbage but runs fortnite 40-60 FPS in a window the size in the image provided, I want to play at that resolution but in a full screen , so I want to find out if I can set a specific resolution in a full screen . The lowest the in game settings go are 720p, please no smart answers like “just run it full screen on 720”, cos my laptop is garbage and 20-30 FPS is not fun.
Any clues?

[image: This is the resolution I want to be full screened]

Comment: Is your gpu by nvidia or amd? I'm not sure if Intel gpu's can set custom resolutions, probably not.

Comment: It’s amd ati...

Answer (score 1):

From what little research I did, it seems that any methods of changing graphics quality and setting custom resolutions within the UE4 config files are outdated and won't work anymore, but there is a 'proper' way of setting custom resolutions.

You can create custom resolutions in your AMD drivers, allowing you to select them in the game, **if the game supports custom resolutions, rather than only allowing pre-selected resolutions**.
(These instructions only work for AMD gpu's)

1. First you need to open your AMD Radeon Settings by right clicking on the desktop and selecting the `AMD Radeon Settings` option
   [image: context menu with the AMD Radeon Settings]
2. Click on the `Display` tab on the bottom of the settings window and click `+ Create` where it says `Custom Resolutions`
   [image: AMD Radeon Settings, Display tab]
3. Change your Horizontal resolution and Vertical resolution to your preferred values and click `✓Save`
   [image: AMD Radeon Settings, custom resolution creation window]
4. After you have saved your custom resolution, it should be available to pick in the game.

There is a chance that Fortnite might not pull the available resolutions from Windows, but rather have a list of pre-set resolutions instead, in which case this will not work.

Comment: I don’t have a Radeon, mines ati and has a different control centre, I’m not blé to download this either I don’t think =/

Comment: ATI was acquired by AMD in 2006. If you are still using drivers that say ATI, not AMD, you should seriously consider updating them. Honestly, updating drivers would probably let you run the game at reasonable fps at a reasonable resolution anyway, if your current drivers are indeed so old.

Comment: I’ll try this when I get home from school but I’m pretty sure my drivers are up to date, should I be using ati or amd drivers?

Comment: Updated my drivers, my radeon settings doesn't have custom resolutions

Comment: What is the model of your gpu? Also, it is quite possible that since you are on a laptop, your radeon settings won't have the custom resolution option.

Comment: There is also the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU), but it is a lot more advanced and much easier to mess something up and it doesn't support all laptops, so I will just link it, but I don't recommend you use it if you're not confident in your tech skills and ability to recover your laptop if something goes wrong.

Comment: I will give the utility a try, I’ve already tried using something similar but it had no full screen option, thanks again

Comment: The utility worked, just not in the way I had hoped, it lowers my screens resolution but I was hoping to just lower the resolution of the game, using my computer constantly in 360p isn’t something I want to do so is there really no program out there that can accomplish this?